# Cannot assign value of type '(String?, Bool, [AnyObject]?, NSError?) -> ()' to

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

After I update Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a) swift 3, I got this error

> Cannot assign value of type '(String?, Bool, [AnyObject]?, NSError?) -> ()' to type 'UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler?'

```
activityview.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: String?, completed:Bool, returnedItems:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
            if !completed {
                print("cancelled")
                return
            }else{
                complele()
            }

        }
```

I have been following this [Cannot assign a value of type '(String!, Bool, [AnyObject]!, NSError!)->Void to a value of type UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598745/cannot-assign-a-value-of-type-string-bool-anyobject-nserror-void-to)

But i still got the error message.

It works well in previous version 7.3.1 swift 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `UIActivityType` instead of `String,` `[Any]` instead of `[AnyObject]` and `Error` instead of `NSError` like this.

```
activityview.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivityType?, completed:Bool, returnedItems:[Any]?, error: Error?) in
    if !completed {
        print("cancelled")
        return
    }else{
        complele()
    }
}
```

Check [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiactivityviewcontrollercompletionwithitemshandler) for more detail.

Comment: still got the error message : Cannot assign value of type '(String?, Bool, [Any]?, Error?) -> ()' to type 'UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler?'

Comment: Thanks you save my day :D

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy Coding :)